# jersey - use custom class in URI of resource

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a custom data class:

```
public static class Data {
    ...
}
```

I want to use this class in the URI of a resource in Jersey. For example:

```
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ResourceTest {
    @GET
    @Path("/data-{data}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("data") final Data data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this possible? I guess I need to inject some kind of converter, which converts the textual representation of a `Data` to a `Data` instance. I have been looking in the documentation, but haven't found something useful so far.

Ofcourse, I can change this to:

```
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ResourceTest {
    @GET
    @Path("/data-{data}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("data") final String input) {
        final Data data = convert(input);
        ...
    }
}
```

But I would rather do the conversion elsewhere/automagically wrt. the resource.

Comment: Not sure why you would need a class to represent data in a GET? Normally, you are only interested in `@PathParam` or `@QueryParam`.

Comment: I am still interested in `@PathParam`, as you can see in the example. I just need to convert from textual representation of a certain class to an instance of the actual class. If possible, I would like to have this conversion outside the resource implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html):

The type of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:

- ...
- **Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument.**
- **Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String)).**
- Have a registered implementation of ParamConverterProvider JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a ParamConverter instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.

So if you provide a constructor `Data(String)` you should be fine.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try. I will try the third option, as some parameters are third party. Thanks!